# Can't create raw socket with admin account on Windows 7

Tags: c, windows, sockets, raw-sockets

According to [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740548%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), creation of raw sockets under Windows 7 is allowed if the account has administrative privileges.  My local account is an admin but it still won't allow me to create the socket.

If I run this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>

void sockerr(char *message)
{
        char errbuf[300];
        FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM, NULL, WSAGetLastError(),
                      0, errbuf, sizeof(errbuf), NULL);
        printf("%s: (%d) %s", message, WSAGetLastError(), errbuf);
}

int main()
{
    int sock;
    struct sockaddr_in sin;
    struct WSAData data;

    if (WSAStartup(2, &data)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error in WSAStartup: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        exit(1);
    }

    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_IGMP);
    if (sock == -1) {
        sockerr("socket failed");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("opened raw socket\n");
    closesocket(sock);
    return 0;    
}
```

I get this:

> socket failed: (10013) An attempt was made to access a socket in a way
>   forbidden by its access permissions.

But I'm an admin:

[image: user account]

This is on my home desktop with Windows 7 Pro.  I have McAfee Antivirus Plus installed, however disabling it had no effect.

This program works fine on my Windows 7 Enterprise laptop.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you run it elevated? (i.e. with "Run as Administrator" or equivalent)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you want to use raw sockets, but it seems the solution is to use [winpcap](http://www.winpcap.org/) If you google you can find examples on using this.
Here is one sample: http://www.binarytides.com/raw-sockets-packets-with-winpcap/

Before I try this I would also make sure that the program is running as Administrator. maybe you are an admin, but the program is not running with that privilege.

Comment: Choosing "Run as Admintrator" did it.  It seems my W7 Enterprise box always starts up a Command Prompt as an Admin, which is why it worked there.  My W7 Pro box doesn't do that, so I had to explicitly start it as an admin.